# copying data from table to table: validate mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, validation, copy

How would I go about validating this query? Currently, I getting some omissions where one row hasn't copied over so I need a bombproof method to check and correct. Query:

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
FROM $UID
";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {

$q = $row['QID'];
$a = $row['answer'];
$c = $row['comment'];

$query = "
INSERT INTO a (UID, QID, answer, comment)
VALUES ('$UID', '$q', '$a', '$c')
";

mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? I dont really see user input in this code hence its not clear validation of what?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more. What do you mean by validation?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the term 'validation' incorrectly. I wish to check that the data has copied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query.

```
INSERT INTO a (UID, QID, answer, comment) 
    SELECT '$UID', QID, answer, comment FROM `$UID`
```

As its an **atomic operation** all the data will be copied in one shot. However you can still verify by using [mysql_info](http://php.net/mysql_info) function. It'll give output like following.

```
Records: 23 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Here Duplicate is the number of rows there were discarded due to duplicate key. If both `Duplicates` and `Warning` are `0` you can say query was successful.

Comment: That is much simpler! - how would I confirm the data has copied correctly?

Comment: From one table to another?

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. However from your previous comments am I to understand that mysql_info is also depreciated? Looking into the alternative APIs now.

Comment: @MikeThrussell yes. all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please accept the answer if this solves you problem.